# How to compare two time-series datasets?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, multiple-comparisons

I am trying to compare the financial performance of green bonds and conventional bonds by looking at their historical bond yields, bond prices etc. individually over a certain period of one year. I have data on several green bonds and conventional bonds but I don't know how to compare them to know whether there are any meaningful differences or higher/lower performance between green bonds and conventional bonds other than by plotting. I thought of students t-test but since the data is time-series I doubt it is appropriate. Also as there are several bonds in both groups of green bonds and conventional bonds, I don't know how to compare them with more than one time-series on both sides. I am an amateur in financial statistical analysis and any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do a test of significance for two unknown means with unknown variance http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/meancomp.htm. Do this test for bonds of similar characteristics (e.g. maturity) and compare the change in yield over a certain timeframe (1 year?). Something like this does not need a fancy time series model.

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of methods to do this depending on your data. Among the more common ways are Regression with Arima error, Vector Auto Regression (VAR), Vector Error Correction Models (VECM), GARCH/ARCH (when variation changes over time) Arima with exogenous variables, and ARDL. None are simple. I would (because it is easier) look at regression with ARIMA errors. The problem is that it is difficult to compare two variables over time if one or both have a trend in them. You might want to look at the cointegration literature to see why.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I am looking into regression with arima errors using xreg in R language. I have a question about xreg- Suppose I am doing an Arima on Green bonds price, can I use the other Green bonds prices as exogenous variables (the xreg) and if yes, is there a limit on the number of variables I can use in xreg ? Since I want to compare green bond price against non-green bond price this makes sense to me or if I include variables like bond yields etc as xreg then I have to do an arima for each bond I have selected? Hope I understood it correctly!

Comment: I am not aware of any practical limit if you have enough points of data. Whether a variable should be a predictor is based on theory and I have no knowledge of bond markets. :) You might look at economic or financial journals for that. You need to be careful about two different methods. One is regression with ARIMA error which is treating the residuals as if they had serial correlation. Another is ARIMA with predictors. With the later you have to remove the error from predictor. I am new to R, but I think Xreg is doing regression with ARIMA error.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply! I used an ARIMA errors model on the data but I still don't get what to look for to see the higher/lower performance. Thought of doing separate ARIMA models and using  residual analysis for comparison but I understand that it is mainly for model selection, so what can I do to compare their performances? Is it correct to compare them based on p values or standard error?

Comment: Also a different question, I have a very short time series data (n<=25) with no acf or pacf but is non stationary. Tried to stationarize the data but it doesn't work maybe due to the small size, is there any way to model such short data? I am thinking of a simple linear regression to model them and using average to compare two such data samples. Is it statistically correct to do? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by higher or lower performance. I commonly use a MAPE with a hold out data set to determine which model works best, but there are many ways to do this. ARIMA uses AIC or something like that to make this decision. I have never seen an analysis of which works best -I am not sure this is knowable. 25 data points is well below the rule of thumb for how many data points you need for time series. If there is seasonality or trend in your data (or both) they will be hard to see. I would try to get more data.